# How to count the number of pairs in a string

Tags: java, string, loops, count

If I enter the string "in the win". How would I go with having the program finding the pairs "in" in that string. There are two. I know to find the occurrences of one character in a string, but how about a pair.

Thank you.

Comment: You could break the string into a string for each word and then compare them.

Comment: What have you tried yourself and can you include the code here so we can help you make it better?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `countMatches` method of the Apache Commons `StringUtils` class (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html).

```
StringUtils.countMatches("in the win", "in");
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean count the number the a string occurs in another?
You may try this code

```
String s = "in the win";
String pair = "in";
int count = 0;
int index;
while(true) {
    index = s.indexOf(pair);
    if(index == -1) break;
    s = s.substring(index + pair.length());
    count++;
}
```